# client ip address

Tags: asp.net, javascript

How to get client ip address in asp.net.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
HttpRequest.UserHostAddress
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userhostaddress.aspx

Comment: Where are you these days. Any update. I have no update from your blog after your last post.

Answer (score 4):

i used that in ASP.NET 3.5
`string ip = Request.UserHostAddress();`