# get user IP in c#

Tags: c#

I want to get the user IP and insert it in a table.I'm using tho following:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Raspunsuri Values(@raspuns,@cnp,@data,'1',@ip)", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cnp", Session["sesiune_cnp"]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@raspuns", textbox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ip", HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
```

But when I look in the table at the column Ip i only get 1...can you give me an explanation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [client ip address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003242/client-ip-address)

Comment: Windows Forms? WCF? WebForms? ... what?

Comment: You have IPv6 installed, and accesssing the web server locally from same machine, so the address comes out as `::1`?..

Comment: Is your problem with getting IP or saving? Print it to console

Comment: Are you sure IP is the last (out of 5 ) columns in the table? You might want to specify the column names explicitly.

Comment: Note to closers: This is not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003242/client-ip-address. Rather, it is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932843/iis-request-userhostaddress-returning-ipv6-1-even-when-ipv6-disabled

Comment: the ip is saved in the table as ::1

Comment: @GSerg did a close-request on the initial question - when there was no hint for "::1" - but you can do a close-request with this other question!

Answer (score 7):

You could use:

```
string ipAddress = Request.UserHostAddress;
```

Answer (score 6):

Your program is likely running correctly. ::1 is the local IP address in IPv6. If you're running this on Windows Vista or later from your local machine then everything is working correctly.

This is a better way to grab a user's IP address though:

```
string ip = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ip))
{
    ip = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
}
```

If the user is behind a proxy of some type then you will get the proxy address rather than the end user's IP address. `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` will typically be the user's real IP address. If that's empty then you should at `REMOTE_ADDR`.

Comment: And if suppose someone else from another computer will access my aplication it will get his IP?