# How to get IPv6 Address in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ipv6, ipv4

I use `Request.UserHostAddress`, can only get IPv4 address, how to get IPv6 address of a visitor?

Comment: A visitor's going to have EITHER a v4 OR a v6 address. They won't be coming in with both.

Comment: Is the user accessing the web site over IPv6 in the first place? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9061470/get-user-ip-in-c-sharp.

Comment: You can always convert an IPv4 address manually to an IPv6: http://www.fnode.com/2009/11/convert-ipv4-into-ipv6/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I assume you're talking about `HttpRequest.UserHostAddress`. It will always return the address that was used to connect to you. If the request was made over IPv6, it will return their IPv6 address; if the request was made over IPv4, it will return their IPv4 address.

You should start by investigating why the request is being made over IPv4. And the folks at http://serverfault.com will probably be of more help on that.

Answer (score 6):

An IPv4 address is translated to an IPv6 address by placing the 4 octets of
the IPv4 address into the rightmost 4 octets of the IPv6 address.

After inserting the 4 octets of the IPv4 address into the
rightmost 4 octets of the IPv6 address, the remaining left-most octets would
be 0 in value.