# does the user login restriction based on IP address support ipv6 for web application?

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, ipv6, ip-restrictions

Does any one know how to restrict the user to login based on an IPV6 address for a web application in c# dot net?

I have already done the functionality using IPV4 and it's working fine, but I wanted to restrict the user based on their IPV6 for the web application.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 9):

In general, yes you can get client IPv6 address via C# code and implements IPv6 restrictions with using `HttpRequest.UserHostAddress` as mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9103977/how-to-get-ipv6-address-in-c) or more accurate with using `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` server variable as described in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735350/how-to-get-a-users-client-ip-address-in-asp-net). If request is made via IPv6 you will have this IP in `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` server variable.

You can also use IIS [IP address restriction module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/ipsecurity/) to configure IPv4 or IPv6 restrictions. Of cause your server application should be configured to work with IPv6.

Take also into account that in Internet mostly you can get IP given by your Internet provider, not real client machine IP. In local networks apparently you can see real IP. It's the same like you see your IP address [here](https://whatismyipaddress.com/), it is different that you see in `ipconfig` or `ifconfig` commands.